# How to make all requests go to a "front controller" in perl

Tags: perl, .htaccess, lwp-useragent, front-controller

I'm making an application in perl for the first time, and wanted to use a front controller approach where all requests go through one script which delegates what pages to load based on the uri.

what my script looks like:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Template;

my $base_url = 'project.local/';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

if ($ua->get($base_url . 'reports'))
{
        my $reports_tt = Template->new(\%options);
        $reports_tt->process('reports.tt', \%varz, 'reports.html') or die $reports_tt->error;
}
```

So on my home.html page, there is a link that points to 'project.local/reports'. I want to load the 'reports.html' page when this link is clicked. Using this approach I can keep all my routes in one place.

But this doesn't load the reports.html page, am I using `LWP::UserAgent->get()` the wrong way? I think I need a way to route all requests to my script in the .htaccess file, but I'm not at all sure how to do that. Could someone kindly assist?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong tool entirely. `LWP::UserAgent` is an HTTP client library — it is used to create and send HTTP requests to other web servers. It cannot be used to respond to HTTP requests, or to write a web server.

Explaining fully how to write a web application in Perl is more than I can reasonably do here, but you may want to take a look at existing Perl web development frameworks like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/), and [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/).

Comment: Thanks, I know about such frameworks but am restricted to not using them

Comment: I believe what I'm looking for is to route all requests to my cgi script in htaccess? Do you know any resources to help with that?

Comment: Use mod_rewrite. Plenty of resources on that.